# Yearly 401k Contribution Limit Question

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-401k

December 22 is the day of my last paycheck for the year. I'm trying to contribute the maximum allowed by the IRS for the year. Since this is the last paycheck I'll get for the year, would that be considered my last contribution for the year? There's another week left in the year but I won't be paid for that week until 2024. Would the amount that will go into the 401k in January for the last week in December be considered part of 2024's contribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since this is the last paycheck I'll get for the year, would that be considered my last contribution for the year?

Yes.

> Would the amount that will go into the 401k in January for the last week in December be considered part of 2024's contribution?

Yes. It doesn't matter what period the salary covers, you're a cash-based taxpayer and the tax event is when you get *paid*.